# Silverstripe 4 use additional custom HTMLEditorField

Tags: silverstripe, tinymce-4, html-editor

In Silverstripe 4 how can we use different HTMLEditor configs ?

I'd like to have two different HTMLEditorFields in the **same environment**.
One with all functionality and all Buttons.
And another one (MyCustomHTMLEditorField) with reduced functionality and e.g. only 3 buttons (underline, italic, bold).

How do you use ::set_active ?

How to extend HTMLEditorConfig ?

Yes, i've read the documentation but How can this be archived?

> There can be multiple configs, which should always be created / accessed using HtmlEditorConfig::get(). You can then set the currently active config using set_active().

Can you provide an Example?

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation at https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/forms/field_types/htmleditorfield/ goes to length about how to define and use `HTMLEditorConfig` sets.

`HTMLEditorConfig::set_active()` is really for if you're intending to set an editor for use in multiple `HTMLEditorField`s in a given form or admin section, or to override the config for all admin sections. It more-or-less sets the 'default' config. That won't be so useful in your case, as it sounds like you want to set a configuration for a given `HTMLEditorField`.

### Setting configuration

This is detailed in the documentation at https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/forms/field_types/htmleditorfield/#adding-and-removing-capabilities

Usually this is done in your `_config.php` (or in some separate class which then gets called from `_config.php` - unless you only need it in a very specific section, in which case you could set this up or call your special class from that admin's `init()` method).

The examples in the documentation here modify the default ('cms') config. This is useful if you want to modify the configuration that is used by default. So do this for your config that you've referred to as having "all functionality and all Buttons".

#### Setting up a new HTMLEditorConfig

Calling `HTMLEditorConfig::get($configName)` will get the existing config based on the name you pass it - but if there is no existing config, it will create a new one. So you could call `$customConfig = HTMLEditorConfig::get('some-custom-config')` - now your `$customConfig` variable holds a *new* configuration that you can configure however you so choose (insert buttons, enable plugins, define whitelisted elements, etc).

Note that there is some configuration that will be required for new config - for example, a "friendly name":

```php
$myConfig->setOption('friendly_name', 'Some Human-readable name');
```

I strongly recommend seeing the [`_config.php` file in silverstripe/admin](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-admin/blob/2/_config.php) for a fairly thorough example of setting up a config.

### Using configuration

This is discussed in the documentation here: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/forms/field_types/htmleditorfield/#specify-which-configuration-to-use

I've already mentioned the `set_active()` - if you're going to set up multiple `HTMLEditorField`s in a form for example you can use that in  your `getCMSFields()` method:

```php
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', HMLEditorField::create('Content')); // This will use the default 'cms' config.
    HTMLEditorConfig::set_active('some-custom-config');
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', HMLEditorField::create('OtherContent')); // This will use the 'some-custom-config' config that you defined.
    // Don't forget to reset to the default.
    HTMLEditorConfig::set_active('cms');
    return $fields;
}
```

You can also, as explained in the docs, set your config by name for a given `HTMLEditorField` which is preferred if you're using a non-default for one one field.

```php
public function getCMSFields()
{
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', HMLEditorField::create('Content')); // This will use the default 'cms' config.
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', HMLEditorField::create('OtherContent')->setEditorConfig('some-custom-config')); // This will use the 'some-custom-config' config that you defined.
    return $fields;
}
```

Note that the syntax I used here is slightly different to the docs - this allows you to avoid passing in the second and third constructor arguments that you're not changing from the defaults. Keeps things a little tidier.

Disclaimer: All of the code above was written from memory, so it may need some tweaks to work correctly.

Comment: @SeppHofer I've updated my answer. Let me know if you need any more help with this.

Comment: Hi Guy! It is working as wanted! (Me silly, I thought I have to extend HTMLEditorConfig  ). Thank you very much!!